# how to use an already open document from another module?

Tags: vba, ms-access, ms-word

i write in a word.document. When it is necessary i write a paragraph in another document and when i finish this document is closed. then i try to copy this paragraph to the first document which remains open.

I try some things but in vain.
when i do this:

```
    Dim wdDocMain As Word.Document
    Set wdDocMain = ActiveDocument
```

i receive the message run time error 4248 This command is not available because no document is open.

when i do this

```
    Dim wdDocMain As Word.Document
    Set wdDocMain = wdApp.Documents.Open(FileName:=pathmaindoc,_ ReadOnly:=False, Visible:=True)
    wdDocMain.Activate
```

i receive the message run time error 91 object variable or with block variable not set.

i find a solution.
To close the open document and then to reopen it like this:

```
    Set wdDocMain = wdApp.Documents.Open(FileName:=pathmaindoc,_ ReadOnly:=False, Visible:=True)
```

but of cource it isnt the best.

Edit.
I would like to thank you in advance for your comments.
i share more lines from my code as Timothy Rylatt suggested.

In my main sub:

```
Dim wdapp As Word.Application
 Dim wdDoc As Word.Document

Set wdapp = New Word.Application
Set wdDoc = wdapp.Documents.Open(FileName:=PathName_HiveDown_Creation,_ ReadOnly:=False, Visible:=True)
wdapp.Visible = True
```

when a condition is met then i call a module (copyparafromtemplatetomain):

```
pathmaindoc = PathName_HiveDown_Creation
pathtemplatedoc = PathName_Template
'wdDoc.Close savechanges:=True
copyparafromtemplatetomain 



Public wdapp As Word.Application
Public wdDocMain As Word.Document

Sub copyparafromtemplatetomain(pathmaindoc As Variant, pathtemplatedoc As Variant, paramain As Variant, paratemplate As Variant, index As Integer)
        
    

Dim wdDocTemplate As Word.Document
    
Dim PathName_MainDoc As Variant
PathName_MainDoc = pathmaindoc

Set wdDocMain = wdapp.ActiveDocument
```

here, i receive run time error 91.
the only way to run is when i close the doc. in the first sub

Comment: try to add Application ->

Dim wdDocMain As Word.Document
Set wdDocMain = Application.ActiveDocument

Comment: If you want objects to be available to multiple modules, need to declare globally as is the case with any variable.

Comment: If you have read your question since editing it, it should be obvious to you that you have two variables named `wdapp`, each with a different scope. You should only have one, which should be global.

Comment: When asking for help with error messages it is essential that you indicate which line of code generates the error. Please take time to read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Timothy Rylatt, thank you. the problem was the multiple definition of wdapp.